# Disappearing files in the cat command

Tags: bash, cat

I am handling a rather large dataset. I have 238 files, for whcih I would like to import their content into excel. In order to do so, I am creating a combined txt file using

```
cat *.pdb > pdb_all.txt
```

When I count the lines (using `wc -l`) in the `pdb_all.txt` file, it contains only 236 lines. Can anyone tell me, if the `cat` command will delete duplicates automatically? If so, I'd very much like to keep both in the correct order. If not, what can have happend in during the cat command that results in two files less?

Comment: What does `wc -l *.pdb` say? `cat` doesn't remove duplicate lines.

Comment: Usual suspect here: is there some file without a end-of-line character at the end? Or some empty file?

Comment: I tried the wc -l *pdb and it showed me that two files were empty. I didn't know that was possible. But quite smart :) Thanks to both of you!

Comment: pdb you say.. are you working with chemists and or VMD? If you are, there are tools to do that, which work quite well. where I am assuming pdb files are protein databases...

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already given by the OP himself:

> I tried the `wc -l *pdb` and it showed me that two files were empty. I
>   didn't know that was possible. But quite smart :)